# INSERT a row at most once per day

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have a Postgres table which (for simplicity) looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt_series (
  i          serial8 PRIMARY KEY,
  userid     int8 NOT NULL,
  date       int4 NOT NULL,
  followers  int4);
```

and I insert like so:

```
INSERT  INTO tt_series (userid,date,followers)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
```

The `date` column is a **timestamp**.

I want to modify the insertion so that the insertion is performed IFF the **current date** (at the moment of insertion) for a given `userid` is *not* on **the same day** as *any* value that's in the database (for that `userid`). (The idea is that each `userid` only gets *at most* one row per day.)

How can that be done?

---

**Example**. Suppose the database has 2 rows, which are:

```
userid  date       followers
1234567 1630072910 50
1234567 1631072910 100
```

and then I get new data that looks like:

```
userid  date       followers
1234567 1631072911 101
```

where the timestamp has increased by 1 second (for userid `1234567`, with respect to the **latest** insertion for userid `1234567`) and the `followers` column has increased by 1 (for userid `1234567`).

In this case the insertion should **not** go through because it's on the **same day** as the lastest insertion for **userid** `1234567` (where "latest" is determined by the value of the `date` column.)

(Notice that we're *not* saying that 24 hours or more must have passed, but only that further insertions for a given `userid` cannot be done on the same **day**. This means that the timestamp difference of 2 insertions could be less than 24 hours, say if some insertion was done at 11pm and the next insertion was done at 1am. Then the difference is 2 hours but the insertion is still valid because they're on different days.)

(Since the day boundaries depend on the timezone, I think, assume the timezone `UTC-0000`.)

(Btw maybe Postgres a has more elegant way of handling timestamps and the idea of "latest insertion for a given row depending on the value of a particular column" (ie. `userid`), in which case that's also a valid answer.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se!  Do you wish for the timestamps to be at least 24hrs after the previous one?

Comment: Try to use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` by `("userid", date_trunc('day', to_timestamp("date")))`.

Comment: `1630072910` is not a date, it's a number - [epoch mania](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/)

Comment: @Vérace Yes, precisely. But the timestamp of new inserts is not given by the database, but it comes with the data to be inserted, so the database should look at that timestamp and decide whether to make the insertion or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use integers to represent timestamps or dates, it is wrong. For the following, I will assume that column `date` is a `timestamp`.

The solution is to create a unique index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tt_series (userid, CAST (date AS date));
```

Then any attempt to insert two rows on the same date will fail.

Comment: *The solution is to create a unique index* No. Look - the duplicates are allowed when the timestamp values are equal precisely ("Suppose the database has 2 rows, which are ..."). Unique index does not allow this. PS. Of course this makes no sense - but...

Comment: @Akina To quote: "I want to modify the insertion so that the insertion is performed IFF the **current date** (at the moment of insertion) for a given `userid` is *not* on **the same day** as *any* value that's in the database (for that `userid`)."

Comment: Additionally. Imagine that the query inserts 2 copies of a row for new day. Unique index will meet dup error for 2nd row and hence will break the whole query, and none row will be inserted whereas the logic needs in one row to be inserted and another one ejected. So the index is a part of complete solution only, the inserting query must be modified too.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, except that now consider I not only want to exclude **exact** dates, but also dates that fall within the **same day** (ie. as opposed to checking for exact date matches, it should be looking for a certain date interval)

Comment: For example, with this solution, the insertion in the example I gave *would indeed* go through, whereas the idea is that it should *not*.

Comment: Since I cast to `date`, which truncates hours, minutes and seconds, any two different timestamps that fall into the same date will cause a conflict.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the [date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html) type. It's good, because it only records the day, but not hours/minutes/seconds. The problem is that `timestamp` *can* be cast to `date`, but `int4` cannot, and I **insist** on my dates being `int4`'s (or, at least, occupying 4 bytes, so I may ditch `int4` in favor of `date`...)

Comment: If Postgres knows how to convert an `int4` to a `date`, let me know

Comment: That depends on the semantics of your integers, which you didn't mention. How do you encode dates as integers?

Comment: My integers don't really encode **dates**, since a date requires a timezone. An integer encodes a **point in time**, the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 -0000`, or something like that. From a *single* **point in time** you can get *multiple* **dates**, depending on which timezone you choose. A date is something like `2021-09-10 11:00:00 -0500`

Comment: "Or something like that": that is precisely the thing you need to know if you want to figure out the date that this number represents. `date` has no time zone, and indeed it wouldn't make any sense. Timestamps can have a time zone. The "or something like that" also emphasizes one of the reasons why it is good to avoid storing timestamps as a number: you lose clarity.